# Formulas of Mellin inversion theorem that involve Riemann zeta function $\zeta (s)$ and floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$

Tags: riemann-zeta, ceiling-and-floor-functions, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

Functions $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $g(s)=\frac{\zeta (s)}{s}$ are related by Mellin inversion theorem, for $c>1$, $\Re(s)>1$.

$$\mathcal{M}_x(f(x))(s)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}(g(s))(x)$$

$$\tag{1.1}f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor =\frac{1}{2 \pi  i} \int_{c-i \infty }^{c+i \infty } \frac{\zeta (s)}{s} x^s \, ds$$

$$\tag{1.2}g(s)=\frac{\zeta (s)}{s}=\int_0^{\infty } \lfloor x\rfloor  x^{-s-1} \, dx$$

Functions $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $g(s)=\frac{-\zeta (s)}{s}$ are related by Mellin inversion theorem, for $0<c<1$, $0<\Re(s)<1$.
$$\mathcal{M}_x(f(x))(s)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}(g(s))(x)$$

$$\tag{2.1}f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor =\frac{1}{2 \pi  i} \int_{c-i \infty }^{c+i \infty } \frac{-\zeta (s)}{s} x^s \, ds$$

$$\tag{2.2}g(s)=\frac{-\zeta (s)}{s}=\int_0^{\infty } (x-\lfloor x\rfloor)  x^{-s-1} \, dx$$

Relations in $(1.1)$ and $(1.2)$ can be derived using [Abel's summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula#Representation_of_Riemann%27s_zeta_function), as is described on that Wikipedia page.

**How relations $(2.1)$ and $(2.2)$ can be derived?**

It is interesting that $(1.1)$ and $(1.2)$ are valid for $\Re(s)>1$ while $(2.1)$ and $(2.2)$ for $0<\Re(s)<1$.

**Are there any other similar formulas that involve $\lfloor x\rfloor$, $\zeta (s)$ and Mellin inversion theorem that are valid at least in some portion of $\Re(s)<0$.**

Comment: For $\Re(s)\in (-1,0)$ it is $\zeta(s)=s\int_0^\infty (\lfloor x\rfloor-x+1/2) x^{-s-1}dx$. The Melin inversion "integral" doesn't converge and needs to be interpreted in the sense of distributions.

Comment: How did you get this formula?

Comment: The proof is the same as for $\Re(s)\in (0,1)$. Substract $\frac12 1_{x <1}$ and use analytic continuation.

Answer (score 3):

For $\Re(s)\in (-1,0)$ we have $$\zeta(s)=s\int_0^\infty (\lfloor x\rfloor-x+1/2) x^{-s-1}dx$$
whence for $\sigma\in (-1,0)$ $$\lfloor x\rfloor-x+1/2 = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac1{2i\pi} \int_{(\sigma)} \frac{\zeta(s)}{s} x^s e^{s^2/k} ds\tag{1}$$
By the Cauchy integral theorem and the polynomial growth of $\zeta(s)$ on vertical strips, the RHS integrals stay the same for all $\sigma < 0$, so that $(1)$ stays valid for all $\sigma < 0$.

That is to say we have the inverse Fourier/Mellin transform in the sense of distributions $$\forall \sigma < 0, \qquad \mathcal{M}^{-1}\left[\frac{\zeta(s)}s\right]_{\Re(s)=\sigma}= \lfloor x\rfloor-x+1/2$$

Comment: So is the integral in the inverse transform in $(1.1)$ and $(2.1)$ only convergent for $\Re(s)\in (-1,\infty)$? Why we can not go beyond $\Re(s)=-1$?

Comment: Convergent in what sense? $\zeta(s)/s$ is not $L^1$ on any vertical line. The functional equation and Stirling formula gives that it is not $L^2$ for $\sigma <0$.

Comment: Is there some other function that its Mellin transform is convergent even for $\Re(s)<-1$ and that can be used to create analytic continuation of zeta function in that region although in a different form than $\zeta(s)/s$.

Comment: $\zeta(s)/(s(s+1)(s+2)\ldots (s+n))$

Comment: Does it still has any sense even in limit as $n\to\infty$ to create analytic continuation in whole complex plane?